# Incorrect text layout in off-topic > migration close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, close-dialog

Today I went to close a question that I felt was better suited for the Mathematics stack exchange. The first thing I noticed is the weird setup of "belongs on" following the name of the website - this seems out of order to me:

[image: img1]

Shouldn't it be written as "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com"? Or shouldn't "Belongs on" be at the top, then you can choose from the radio buttons? The current layout just makes no sense to me.

Comment: Designed the dialog Yoda?

Comment: [I posted another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346184/backwards-the-migration-close-reason-text-is) on Meta.SE because I didn't see this one.